# Sorting Nodes (Linked-list) C++

Tags: c++, sorting, linked-list, nodes

I'm trying to sort a linked-list. I have a Node called head and it's pointing to the next node, etc.

But when I try to sort the Nodes by the value they carry, I get the sort working because I see it printing out the stuff in the if-statement, but I'm not getting back the linked-list. Where did I go wrong?

```
Node* head;
void sortlist(){

Node * runner = head;
Node * runner2;

for(runner = head; runner->next != NULL; runner = runner->next){
    for(runner2 = runner->next; runner2->next != NULL; runner2 = runner2->next){
        if(runner->freq < runner2->freq){
            cout<< runner->freq<< " is LT "<<runner2->freq<< endl;
            Node * temp = runner;
            runner = runner2;
            runner2 = temp;
        }
    }
}

head = runner;
}
```

I'm only getting back the first Node.

Comment: `head = runner;`. I don't even need to go deep to know this is false.

Comment: The swapping seems to be working though, I think I'm just returning the wrong node, or maybe I lost the link?

Comment: The swapping is not working. You need to be swapping `runner->freq` and `runner2->freq`, not the pointers themselves. Plus you need to get the algorithm right, even if you swapped the right things, this code would not sort.

Comment: You're not actually swapping anything other than your own pointers into the list. The list isn't being relinked, and you just point the head back at the last node after you're done.

Comment: Welcome to SO! When dealing with pointers it is helpful to draw pictures to help you understand what is going on. From there, you can also use a debugger or cout statements to trace through your code to find out why it isn't doing what you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to swap two elements in a linked list, consider what you need to change. For example, to get from

```
Head -> First -> Second -> (NULL)
```

to

```
Head -> Second -> First -> (NULL)
```

you need to update: `Head.next`, `First.next` *and* `Second.next`. You don't change *any* of those things when trying to swap nodes, so it can't possibly do what you expect.

---

Just swapping the *values* (ie, `swap(runner->freq, runner2->freq)`) would be much simpler.

Comment: yup swapping values is the way to go in most cases.

Comment: +1 for suggesting swapping values rather than messing with the pointers.

Comment: Swapping the values is certainly easier, but that can have performance implications if the linked-list contains large chunks of memory in its nodes, like a large struct for instance.

Comment: That's true, and it's certainly worthwhile to learn how to swap nodes correctly - it just seemed like a long road from the problem statement.

Answer (score 2):

you will stop when `runner->next == NULL;`, which is supposed to be the last element. And then you set  `head = runner;`, which means the head will always be the last element after this routine. Furthermore, I do not trust this swapping.

It seems you vaguely want to do an [insertion sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort). If you want to do a simple sorting on linked lists, I suggest you to use [selection sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort): You create another empty list `l2`, and each time you remove the minimum element from your first list, and add it as the head of `l2`. The code for the second list is simple:

```
void prepend(Node* node, Node** list){
   //null checks if you want
   node->next = *list;
   *list=node->next;
}
```